# Using JbossSerialization instead of java Serialization for JBOSS remote invocations

Tags: performance, serialization, jboss

I’m using Jboss 5, and invoking hundreds of EJBs with complex parameters. 
There are some performance issues that I think are related to Java Serialization

As Jboss using JbossRemoting for remote invocations, I would like to use `JbossSerialization` to optimize serialization performance.

Like explained [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossremoting/docs/guide/2.5/html/ch08.html), I'm using

```
-DSERIALIZATION="org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.jboss.JBossSerializationManager"
```

at server side and in invocation code.

But `JavaSerializationManager` is still used by Jboss.

Can someone explain or exemplify how to configure JBOSS for using `JBossSerializationManager`.

In other words, what is the easiest way to make already deployed EJB application using Jboss Serialization instead of java Serialization?

Comment: Better to ask this in the JBoss community forums.

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing because JBoss remoting is a component that is used by JBoss Server.  If you were using JBoss Remoting standalone that works (sort of).  JBoss Server has its own set of config files.

For EJB3 calls you will need to update the InvokerLocator connection string in the location defined [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossremoting/2.5.4.SP1/userguide/html_single/#d0e1314).  It looks something like below...

```
socket://myhost:6500/?datatype=test&loaderport=6501&marshaller=org.jboss.test.remoting.marshall.dynamic.remote.http.TestMarshaller&unmarshaller=org.jboss.test.remoting.marshall.dynamic.remote.http.TestUnMarshaller
```

The parameter you want to add is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossremoting/docs/guide/2.5/html/chapter-configuration.html) under 5.11.1

> SERIALIZATIONTYPE (actual value is 'serializationtype') - indicates the serialization implementation to use. Currently, the only possible values are 'java' and 'jboss'. Java serialization is the default. Setting to 'jboss' will cause JBoss Serialization to be used. In implementation, this equates to the parameter that will be passed to the SerializationStreamFactory.getManagerInstance() method. This configuration can be set as an invoker locator url parameter (e.g. socket://myhost:5400/?serializationtype=jboss) or as an entry to the configuration Map passed when constructing a remoting client or server.

So you would append
`&serializationtype=jboss`

Note that there is no way to use JBoss Serialization for JMS that I could find.